# wait-for-it always times out in docker environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, timeout

I'm trying to establish a situation where a docker container waits for a container to start answering a ping or timeout after 20 seconds and run a script regardless of success or timeout.

I found a handy script called wait-for-it that should do the job brilliantly.
https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

I ran tests on my local environment and everything ran smoothly, but when I tried this in the production environment no matter what the address is, even localhost, I get a operation timed out and the command never gets called.

This is the entrypoint from my docker-compose file:

`entrypoint: ["wait-for-it", "127.0.0.1:80", "-t 20", "--", "script", "127.0.0.1"]`

Wait for it is copied to `/usr/local/bin` and chmodded with a `a+x`. I have done the tests in the container and calling `wait-for-it` works.

After googling around I found that a common cause for such a behaviour is the absence of netcat, but I have verified that said netcat is in fact in the `apt install` portion and that the command `nc` is in fact accessible in the container, so this should not be a case of a missing netcat.

The containers base is this one:
https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/3d43bcf8ddd26ae85fd6a63a7e1d502b445c9cce/3.9/bullseye/Dockerfile

Comment: `127.0.0.1` means _this_ container; the `wait-for-it` call will never succeed, because the service in this container can't start until `wait-for-it` starts it, and `wait-for-it` can't start until the service is running.  Do you mean a different container, maybe using the mechanisms described in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)?

Comment: You also may need `-t 20` to be two separate arguments, or to not have a space in between.

Comment: Ah, I was a bit obscure on the wording, the address ```127.0.0.1``` is just a place holder for a containers address, but even if that was the case shouldn't the script run when the operation timed out -message appears since this is not ```--strict```?